# C#/.NET: Detect whether program is being run as a service or a console application

Tags: c#, .net, service

I have a C#/.NET program that can run both as a console application and as a service.
Currently I give it a command-line option to start as a console application, but I would like to avoid that.

Is it possible to programmatically detect whether my program is being started as a service?

If it was pure Win32, I could try starting as a service with StartServiceCtrlDispatcher and fall back to console if it returned ERROR_FAILED_SERVICE_CONTROLLER_CONNECT, but System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run() pops up an errordialog if it fails and then just returns without signaling an error to the program.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the OP didn't know this was a dupe because the question that was already answered has a terrible name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rasmus,  [this is the earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200163/am-i-running-as-a-service#200183).

From the answers it seems the most popular way is to use a simple command line option, or try accessing the Console object in a try catch block (in a Service the Console is not attached to the process and trying to access it throws an exception).

Or if you're having trouble testing/debugging the service, move code into a separate dll assembly and create a seprate test harness (winforms/console etc).

(Just noticed that Jonathan has added his solution to the end of the question.)

Answer (score 39):

[Environment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) will do the magic.

Comment: What if the service is running on Windows XP with "Allow this service to interact with the desktop" set?

Comment: It will stop doing magic, that's what :)

Comment: This also breaks under various Cygwin shells and the like. You need to use the WMI force to do this properly.

Comment: It doesn't really do any magic when running as a process in Docker without the 'interactive terminal' switch. Console.ReadKey will fail, but Environment.UserInteractive returns true.

Comment: It won't! Run you app in LocalSystem context `psexec -s YourApp.exe` and `Environment.UserInteractive == false`

Answer (score 8):

Might want to try SessionId property of the Process object.  In my experience SessionId is set to 0 if the process is running a service.

Comment: This method is simple, fast and reliable. It won't tell you if your process *is* the service, or merely being run as a child of a service, but this does work (note that it only works on Vista and above - prior to that the first user log-in session would also be session ID zero and shared with the services).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it, but it's possible that [Process.GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx) will help - under console mode the process name would be the same as the executable, whereas I'd expect (and again, please check!) that when running as a service it would be different.

Comment: I thought that the process was still (usually) the same exe itself, unless you go out of your way to rehost via svchost.exe or similar...

Comment: Could be - hard to test from my current desk :(

Comment: At least under mono, the process name does change to the executing entity (i.e. if run with mono-service the process is now called mono-service). Haven't tried as a windows service

Answer (score 3):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);
const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;

IntPtr iStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

if (iStdOut == IntPtr.Zero)

{    
    app.RunAsWindowsService = true;

}

// Run as Service
if (runAsWindowsService)                                
{
     // .....
     ServiceBase.Run(myService);
}
else 
{
    // Run as Console
    // Register Ctrl+C Handler...
}
```

Comment: Does this work if the service is running in interactive mode?

Answer (score 3):

Using the ParentProcessUtilities struct from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346055/620178) about finding a parent process, you can do this:

```cs
static bool RunningAsService() {
    var p = ParentProcessUtilities.GetParentProcess();
    return ( p != null && p.ProcessName == "services" );
}
```

Note that the process name for the parent process does not include the extension ".exe".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work, but you may want to try using PInvoke with [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/article.php/c1437/) code and checking if the parent is "services.exe".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up detecting whether or not I was in a console application by checking [Console.IsErrorRedirected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.iserrorredirected.aspx).  It returned "false" for console apps, and "true" for the non-console apps I tested.  I could have also used [IsOutputRedirected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.isoutputredirected.aspx).

I imagine there are circumstances where these will not be accurate, but this worked well for me.

Comment: IsOutputRedirected will be true if the console application is started from the console and output is redirected or piped (> or |).