# regex - unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, regex, escaping

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/959982/101055

I am trying to use:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters.Add("goodName1", "asdf");
parameters.Add("goodName2", "qwerty");
string text = "this is my {goodName1} template {goodName2} string";
text = Regex.Replace(text, "\{(.+?)\}", m => parameters[m.Groups[1].Value]);
```

I get 2 build errors on `\{(.+?)\}`, on `{` and `}` exactly.

> ERROR > Unrecognized escape sequence

What is wrong here?

Comment: i did try and ask in the original thread but no answer, so posted here - hope it's ok.

Comment: i also edited the original (link above) to fix this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognized escape sequence for path string containing backslashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"\{(.+?)\}", m => parameters[m.Groups[1].Value]);
```

A few more details.

The @ sign defines a Verbatim String Literal.  This basically says tells the compiler that the string in quotes is not escaped.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Optionally, you could have simply doubled up on the back slashes. e.g.:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "\\{(.+?)\\}", m => parameters[m.Groups[1].Value]);
```

But, IMHO, the @ sign is much more readable.

Comment: *thnx* that worked. will accept the answer as soon as it allows me (12 minutes).

Comment: @b0x0rz: It defines a "verbatim string literal" which means the string is NOT escaped.  More info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You need to double escape your `\` characters so that they're a `\` literal within the string, and not used as a string-level escape sequence.

```
"\\{(.+?)\\}"
```

Within the string, this has a value of `\{(.+?)\}`

Alternatively you can use the `@""` literal:

```
@"\{(.+?)\}"
```

Which has an identical value.

---

When you need to add a newline to a string, you use an escape sequence, `"\n"`. Strings literals use the `\` as an escape character to assist in coding characters that don't exist on a standard keyboard, or are otherwise difficult to place within a string. Regular expressions require using the same `\` character to escape special characters in the pattern. This means that the `\` character must be escaped to be used as a literal value in the string, which is `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `@` to escape an entire string, or you can put a double slash, `\\` to escape each occurence.

[Here is a good article on strings and escaping them from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

An example from the article:

```
@"c:\Docs\Source\a.txt"  // rather than "c:\\Docs\\Source\\a.txt"
```