# String interpolation C#: Documentation of colon and semicolon functionality

Tags: c#, syntax, string-interpolation

I found this codegolf answer for the FizzBuzz test, and after examining it a bit I realized I had no idea how it actually worked, so I started investigating:

```
for(int i=1; i<101;i++)
    System.Console.Write($"{(i%3*i%5<1?0:i):#}{i%3:;;Fizz}{i%5:;;Buzz}\n");
```

I put it into dotnetfiddle and established the 1st part works as follows:

```
{(BOOL?0:i):#}
```

When BOOL is true, then the conditional expression returns 0 otherwise the number.

However the number isn't returned unless it's `<> 0`. I'm guessing this is the job the of `:#` characters. I can't find any documentation on the `:#` characters workings. Can anyone explain the **colon/hash** or point me in the right direction?

Second part:

```
{VALUE:;;Fizz}
```

When `VALUE = 0` then nothing is printed. I assume this is determined by the first `;` character [end statement]. The second `;` character determines 'if `VALUE <> 0` then print what's after me.'

Again, does anyone have documentation on the use of a **semicolon** in string interpolation, as I can't find anything useful.

Comment: `what other 'advanced' functionality exists in string interpolation that I may not be aware of?` is going to be far too broad, you should probably remove this

Comment: [Composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Anything behind a colon `:` is just a plain old simple format string (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings). (Not including the colon of the ternary inline-if operator `condition ? exprA : exprB`, of course)

Comment: @elgonzo - that would be the case, but there's no ? mark before the colon in the first, or second parts of this.

Comment: @JonBarker, but there is a ternary inline-if operator in your code example. I am not sure what you are trying to say here...

Comment: for your `;;`, see [String Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the link @DavidG, there's nothing in there about # or ; though

Comment: Thanks for your input all - it makes sense now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the commenters! Fast response.

**The # is defined here (Custom specifier)**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier

> The "#" custom format specifier serves as a digit-placeholder symbol.
>   If the value that is being formatted has a digit in the position where
>   the "#" symbol appears in the format string, that digit is copied to
>   the result string. Otherwise, nothing is stored in that position in
>   the result string. Note that this specifier never displays a zero that
>   is not a significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the
>   string. It will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the
>   number that is being displayed.

**The ; is defined here (Section Seperator):**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator

> The semicolon (;) is a conditional format specifier that applies
>   different formatting to a number depending on whether its value is
>   positive, negative, or zero. To produce this behavior, a custom format
>   string can contain up to three sections separated by semicolons...

Answer (score 3):

This is all covered in the [String Interpolation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), especially the section on the [Structure of an Interpolated String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#structure-of-an-interpolated-string), which includes this:

```
{<interpolatedExpression>[,<alignment>][:<formatString>]}
```

along with a more detailed description for each of those three sections.

The format string portion of that structure is defined on separate pages, where you can use [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) and [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) formats for numeric types as well as [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) formats for date and time types. There are also options for [Enum values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings), and you can even create your own [custom format provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2).

It's worth taking a look at the custom format provider documentation just because it will also lead you to the [`FormattableString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=netframework-4.7.2) type. This isn't well-covered by the documentation, but my understanding is this type *may in theory* allow you to avoid re-parsing the interpolated string for each iteration when used in a loop, thus potentially improving performance (though in practice, there's no difference at this time). I've [written about this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761121/performance-issue-comparing-to-string-format), and my conclusion is MS needs to build this into the framework in a better way.