# Capturing the main thread SynchronizationContext or Dispatcher from a library

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, synchronization

I have a C# library that would like to have the ability to Send/Post work to the "main" ui thread (if one exists).
This library may be used by:

- A winforms application
- A native application (with UI)
- A console application (with no UI)

In the library I'd like to capture something (A SynchronizationContext, a Dispatcher, a Task Scheduler, or something else) during initialization, that will allow me to (at a later time) Send/Post work to the main thread (if the main thread has that ability--i.e. it has a message pump).  For example, the library would like to put up some Winforms UI on the main thread if and only if the main application has the ability for me to get to the main thread.

Things I've tried:

1. A [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx):
   Capturing this works fine for a Winforms application (a [WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext.aspx) will be installed as the [Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) SynchronizationContext.  This also works fine for the console app--since I can detect that the Current SynchronizationContext is null (and thus, know that I don't have the ability to send/post work to the main thread).  The problem here is the native UI application: It has the ability (i.e. it has a message pump), but the Current Synchronization context is null and thus I can't differentiate it from the Console app case.   If I could differentiate, then I could simply install a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext on the main thread, and I'm good to go.
2. A [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907):  Capturing this using [Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) creates a new SynchronizationContext.  Thus, in all situations I will get back a Dispatcher.  However, for a Console app, using `Dispatcher.Invoke` from a background thread will hang (as expected).  I could use [`Dispatcher.FromThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.fromthread) (which doesn't create a Dispatcher for the thread if one doesn't exist).  But the native UI application will return a null Dispatcher using this method, and so then I'm, again, stuck not being able to distinguish the UI application from the console application.
3. A [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx): I could use [FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx). This has the same problems as the SynchronizationContext.  I.e. Before calling FromCurrentSyncronizationContext, I'd have to check if the Current SynchronizationContext is null (which will be the case for the Console app and the native ui application).  So, again I can't distinguish the native ui application from the console application.

I, of course, could have the user of my library specify whether or not it is a UI application when they call my `Initialize` method, but I was hoping to avoid that complication for the user of the library if possible.

Comment: I am using C# library in MFC. This library has got TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() call. when I run MFC application it throws exception saying that 'current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler'.Any idea how to deal with it? I am not directly using C# library in MFC,but I have created a wrapper in managed C++ and I am using this wrapper in MFC application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not in general possible, a library that's apt to be used in threads cannot make any assumptions about which particular thread is the UI thread.  You can capture Synchronization.Current but that will only work correctly if your initialization method is called from the UI thread.  That's not terribly unusual to work out well, like TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() tends to work by accident, but not a guarantee.  You can add a check, if Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState() doesn't return STA then the odds that you are not being called from the UI thread are very high.  SynchronizationContext.Current will also often be null in that case, another way to check.

The (arguably) better ways are to just not worry about it and let the client code figure it out, it won't have any trouble marshaling the callback.  Or to expose a property of type SynchronizationContext so that the client code can assign it.  Or add it as a constructor argument.  Throw an InvalidOperationException if you are ready to Post but find out that it is still null, that's an oversight that the client programmer only makes once.

Answer (score 1):

I think you *should* make this an option to your `Initialize` method (or somehow allow your caller to request UI interaction), to me that just makes more sense.  I don't know the specifics but these seems to me to be a "courteous" thing to do, let your caller decide if they want you to or want to support your UI.  I would take it one step further and even as the caller to supply a synchronization context.  But that's my opinion.

To answer your question, there are a few "hacks" you can use to determine if you're running in a console applicaiton.  This SO question has some information on that: [C#/.NET: Detect whether program is being run as a service or a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207896/c-net-detect-whether-program-is-being-run-as-a-service-or-a-console-applicati)

Comment: Thanks.  For a native MFC application what SynchronizationContext should they provide?  A WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext would work just fine, but it would seem somewhat strange for them to provide that.

Comment: I would have to do a bit of research or consult someone who is more familiar with MFC, it's been a _really_ long time since I've worked with MFC so I'm not even sure.  My point was just that I'm not a big fan of "baking in" those kinds of choices, openness and flexibility usually turns out to be a better choice.

Answer (score -1):

Change the library initialization to have a SyncronizationContext parameter.  If the parameter is null then the library doesn't need to do anything special, if not null Post/Send GUI updates there.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is exactly what [`AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager.createoperation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for.[“Implementing the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern”](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a34yad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> The Event-based Asynchronous Pattern provides a standardized way to package a class that has asynchronous features. If implemented with helper classes like [AsyncOperationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), your class will work correctly under any application model, including ASP.NET, Console applications, and Windows Forms applications.

It is up to the caller to decide if they want to call your API on the UI thread or not. If they do, this will capture the context and events will go through the message pump in order. In a Console application you can get the same behavior if you install a SynchronizationContext such you get for free by using [`AsyncContext.Run()`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) from the `Nito.AsyncEx` nuget package. No need for an extra property or to have to write the conditional code yourself. If no serializing synchronization context is available, [`AsyncOperation.Post()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperation.post%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will use the fake synchronization context available to Console apps which just queue the event to the threadpool instead (meaning that the posts may not execute in order). Just remember to call `AsyncOperation.OperationCompleted()` or `AsyncOperation.PostOperationCompleted()` when done.

> In the library I'd like to capture something (A SynchronizationContext, a Dispatcher, a Task Scheduler, or something else) during initialization

This is exactly what [`AsyncOperationManager.CreateOperation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asyncoperationmanager.createoperation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does, and in an environment-agnostic way. But you should try to pair this with a call to `OperationCompleted()` which maybe would be more difficult given the API you want to expose. The easiest way to use `AsyncOperation` would be to start an operation when your library actually starts an operation instead of during initialization. Or by having the initialization routine return an `IDisposable` context object handle which would signal to the consumer that they need to manage its lifetime.