# Service detection for .NET Core

Tags: .net, service, .net-core

Could you please suggest a method for `.NET Core` which is able to detect in runtime whether the code is executed within a service or not?

I have the working code for `.NET Framework` but I think it is impossible to port it because it is based on properties unavailable in `.NET Core 1.1`.

Comment: You need to brush up on your google skills.  A quick search yielded multiple hits, including this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207896/c-net-detect-whether-program-is-being-run-as-a-service-or-a-console-applicati

Comment: Sorry your link is not for .NET Core and that is my problem. I have working code for .NET

Comment: Wouldn't it still apply?  Either way, you  need to show evidence that you researched this (the number one reason listed on the down vote button);

Comment: No. I can't port it because most of the properties are unavailable in .NET Core 1.1

Comment: Like Environment.UserInteractive

Comment: If this is in the context of a library, it's almost always better to *let the caller tell you* or *let the caller supply callbacks* such that you *don't* have to (imperfectly) try to determine if you're running in the context of a service.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, this is in the context of a library. But probably I can't do what you are suggesting because I can't change the interfaces right now

Comment: .NET Core only supports console and web apps now. It does not have anything like Windows service.

Comment: @LexLi I think you can host .net core as windows service, look here http://dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-host-your-aspnet-core-in-a-windows-service/ for example

Comment: Or this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService/

Comment: .net core has no ServiceBase so i created an alternative (for which petter kottas has made a nice API on top of). Added an answer based on my experience while implementing https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service

Comment: @rory.ap this question is valid as it applies to .net core APIs and implementations. I spent some time researching this only to find out that there is no fool-proof way. even the property for Environment.UserInteractive can fail (looked at .net framework reference source, corefx, other implementations like NSSM, libs for GO that docker uses).

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly possible with public managed APIs in .NET Core. `Environment.UserInteractive` is defaulted to a fixed value and checks to test how stdout is wired up can yield unexpected results as well for various situations (like subprocesses with & without stdout wiring).

In my [sample implementation](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnet-win32-service/blob/e93e0f7b42c056bbb81db84a7d87d7d65f3579ae/samples/TestService/Program.cs#L24) for service hosting APIs i ended up requiring the service registration to add a command line argument (`--run-as-service`) when the executable is installed as a windows service (in this app, wen called with `--register-service`). A lot of non-.net applications work this way, including docker.