# .NET Core 1.1 console app always exits/crashes as systemd service on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, daemon, systemd

I'm trying to create a simple echo service, which works with the `systemd` init system. All is OK and it's even starting after quick-deploy, BUT it exits (or crashes) quickly, when I'm trying to figure out its state via `systemctl status <service>` command.

The logic is simple, here I'm providing the next sources:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hw
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int delay = 1000;
        private static Random random = new Random();

        static async Task Handle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"tick tack... {random.Next()}");
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            await Handle();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async() => await Handle());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**hw.service (systemd config file)**

```
[Unit]
Description=HW Echo Service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/netcore/hw
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/netcore/hw/hw.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-echo-hw

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Help-script, init.sh** (you may also use `chmod +x init.sh`, if want to try it on your local system):

```
dotnet build
dotnet publish

echo "\nPreparing binaries for the service directory:\n"
rm -rf /var/netcore/hw
mkdir /var/netcore /var/netcore/hw
cp -R bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/publish/* /var/netcore/hw
ls -la /var/netcore/hw

echo "\nInitializing the systemd service:"
systemctl stop hw.service
rm /etc/systemd/system/hw.service
cp hw.service /etc/systemd/system/hw.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable hw.service
systemctl start hw.service
systemctl status hw.service
```

Logs:

- Build/Deploy: https://pastebin.com/9hwbxrCX
- From `journalctl -fu hw.service`: https://pastebin.com/SSMNbgtS
- From `systemctl status hw.service`, right after first deploy: https://pastebin.com/3HySgdsi

What am I waiting for?

I want my service run as other my services (ASP.NET Core) are running (with active/green state) as `systemd` services. As for the ASP.NET Core projects, there are NO problems, as for the simple console - they are...

How to fix my problems?

Thanks

Comment: But you are running in non-interactive mode, so I suppose Console.ReadLine does not work. Try something like Console.CancelKeyPress event in combination with ManualResetEvent.

Comment: @Evk Thanks a lot, I have done what you have suggested me & my service is working now. I didn't know about interactive mode earlier. Also, I noticed, that the current version of the .NET Core doesn't have the `Environment.UserInteractive` property. Also, there is interesting info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758423/service-detection-for-net-core , thanks a lot again. If you want, you may write an answer to this question, I shall accept it.

Comment: Glad that it helped, but as for writing answer I just not sure exactly about the reasons, don't have much experience with .net core yet. In full .NET for example, as I remember, Console.ReadLine will still work in non-interactive mode (will block) and Console.ReadKey will throw an exception. Anyhow if you are not expecting any input (running as a service) it is good to not use methods such as Console.ReadLine anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Evk** has suggested to use `ManualResetEvent`, I've done the next:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hw
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int delay = 1000;
        private static Random random = new Random();
        private static ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static async Task Handle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"tick tack... {random.Next()}");
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            await Handle();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async() => await Handle());
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) => 
            {
                // Cancel the cancellation to allow the program to shutdown cleanly.
                eventArgs.Cancel = true;
                resetEvent.Set();
            };
            resetEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Now all is working & service doesn't stop/crash.

Comment: You can replace `Task.Factory.StartNew(async() => await Handle());` with just `Handle()` by the way.

Comment: @Evk I've done this only because of skipping warning in Visual Code editor from OmniSharp :) As for the logic, yes, I'm agree. Factory doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can use extension method like this `public static class TaskExtensions { public static void Forget(this Task task) { } }` to clarify your intentions and remove that warning (though of course it's usually not a good idea to ignore task, because it might throw exceptions you won't observe).

Comment: @Evk Thanks a lot :)