# Determining the color of a pixel in a bitmap using C# in a WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

The only way I found so far is `System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel()`, but Microsoft has warnings for `System.Drawing` that are making me wonder if this is the "old way" to do it. Are there any alternatives?

---

Here's what Microsoft says about the `System.Drawing` namespace. I also noticed that the System.Drawing assembly was not automatically added to the references when I created a new WPF project.

> **System.Drawing Namespace**
>
> The System.Drawing namespace provides access to GDI+ basic graphics functionality. More advanced functionality is provided in the System.Drawing.Drawing2D, System.Drawing.Imaging, and System.Drawing.Text namespaces.
>
> The Graphics class provides methods for drawing to the display device. Classes such as Rectangle and Point encapsulate GDI+ primitives. The Pen class is used to draw lines and curves, while classes derived from the abstract class Brush are used to fill the interiors of shapes.
>
> **Caution**
>
> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx

Comment: Which warnings? can you share them with us in the question?

Comment: As far as I can see they only tell you not to use System.Drawing in a service (which make sense). There is nothing wrong with using it inside a WPF application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390532/system-drawing-in-windows-or-asp-net-services) and the top answer for a good explanation.  But to answer your question, there is nothing wrong or "old" with using the System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetPixel() method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code

```
    public Color GetPixel(BitmapSource bitmap, int x, int y)
    {
        Debug.Assert(bitmap != null);
        Debug.Assert(x >= 0);
        Debug.Assert(y >= 0);
        Debug.Assert(x < bitmap.PixelWidth);
        Debug.Assert(y < bitmap.PixelHeight);
        Debug.Assert(bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel >= 24);

        CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(bitmap, new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1));
        byte[] pixel = new byte[bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8];
        cb.CopyPixels(pixel, bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8, 0);
        return Color.FromRgb(pixel[2], pixel[1], pixel[0]);
    }
```