# ASP.NET MVC: System.Drawing not supported

Tags: asp.net, wcf

**What I'm trying to**

I'm trying to let a user enter the name of a website in a textbox and click on a button. When the button has been clicked the website URL should be sent to a method which will use a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) to navigate to the website and take a screenshot of it. Further it should afterwards grab this screenshot and generate a thumbnail of it.

**... And the tricky part**

The tricky thing is that according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) the `System.Drawing` should not be used in neither Windows or ASP.NET services, which leaves me with 2 approaches:

- Ignore the suggestion from MSDN and implement the class which contains the necessary methods.
- Create a WCF Service with the necessary methods.

The second approach sounds to me that it almost violates the suggestion on MSDN anyway since I implement it in a ASP.NET MVC (connecting to the WCF Host)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation indeed has this warning, however, thousands of developers on thousands of sites have used the classes in the `System.Drawing` namespace without much issue.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390532/system-drawing-in-windows-or-asp-net-services) other SO question exactly about this issue, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528525/alternatives-to-system-drawing-for-use-with-asp-net) one.

Comment: So you think it would be "fine" to implement the class in my ASP.NET solution, and the WCF service would be redundant? - Friends of mine told me to use a WCF service to also avoid trust problems since some of the classes that I use requires Full Trust...

Comment: @ebb - The only issues that crop up seem to be under load (and normally to do with resources that are not cleaned up) - you are a better judge of those conditions for your app than I am.

Comment: Wrap every (seriously) System.Drawing class instance in a using(){} clause, and you're good to go.