# how to draw in asp.net(c#)?

Tags: asp.net, system.drawing, system.drawing.imaging

how to draw next image with labels in rectangles? thanks for help:

[image]

Comment: +1: I'm gonna need to do this fairly soon too, so I'm interested in the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the different classes in the [`System.Drawing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace.

Alternatively, use one of the [many](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/Painter.aspx) [drawing](http://www.devmaster.net/news/index.php?storyid=2168) libraries around.

---

Note:

The documentation on MSDN gives the following warning:

> Classes within the System.Drawing namespace are not supported for use within a Windows or ASP.NET service. Attempting to use these classes from within one of these application types may produce unexpected problems, such as diminished service performance and run-time exceptions. For a supported alternative, see Windows Imaging Components.

However, I and [others who have done so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390532/system-drawing-in-windows-or-asp-net-services) have not found problems. Even [MSDN magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301375.aspx) suggests it...

Comment: What sort of control do you use as a drawing surface?

Comment: @Jackson Pope - You don't.  You simply download an image, the image gets trapped on the server and an in-memory bitmap is returned.

Comment: @Jackson: You can just use an Image control, and render an image using the classes in System.Drawing.

Comment: Thanks to both @Oded and @Mystere, that info will definitely come in handy in a week or so!

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good, detailed article at the 4guysfromrolla web site.  I used this the first time I needed to do such a thing, and I still use the same pattern.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111734/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042209-1.aspx

This one is fairly good as well, but nowhere near as well-explained as the first one.  http://blogs.sitepoint.com/generating-asp-net-images-fly/