# c# Tiff files compression methodology

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, tiff

I am trying to understand and implement a piece of code for Tiff compression.

I have already used 2 separate techniques - Using 3rd party dll's LibTiff.NEt (1st method is bulky) and the Image save method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (2nd method works only on windows 7 machine but not on windows 2003 or 2008 server).

Now I am looking to explore this 3rd method.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

        int width = 800;
        int height = 1000;
        int stride = width/8;
        byte[] pixels = new byte[height*stride];

        // Try creating a new image with a custom palette.
        List<System.Windows.Media.Color> colors = new List<System.Windows.Media.Color>();
        colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red);
        colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
        colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);
        BitmapPalette myPalette = new BitmapPalette(colors);

        // Creates a new empty image with the pre-defined palette

        BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
            width,
            height,
            96,
            96,
            System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.BlackWhite,
            myPalette, 
            pixels, 
            stride);


FileStream stream = new FileStream(Original_File, FileMode.Create);
TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.Ccitt4;
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
encoder.Save(stream);
```

But I don't have a full understanding of what is happening here.

There is obviously some kind of a memory stream that the compression technique is being applied to. But I am a bit confused how to apply this to my specific case. I have an original tiff file, I want to use this method to set its compression to CCITT and save it back. Can anyone help?

I copied the above code and the code runs. But my end output file is a solid black background image. Although on the positive side it is of the correct compression type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616002%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffcompressoption%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1585c562-f7a9-4cfd-9674-6855ffaa8653/parameter-is-not-valid-for-compressionccitt4-on-windows-server-2003-and-2008?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: Why did you add the asp.net tag?  Are you doing this is an asp.net project?

Comment: yes. I have a web page, that allows user input, which is then converted into a tiff file. This tiff file's original compression type is LZW. I need it in CCITT compression format.

Comment: You might be having issues because [the Drawing namespace is not supported in ASP.NET services](http://stackoverflow.com/q/390532/21727)

Comment: `PixelFormats` is in  `System.Windows.Media`, not `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`.

Comment: thanks, now my code runs, but the output file I get doesn't have any image or properties...when I open the file I get the message windows photo editor cannot open the file, because it is being used in another application.

Comment: I disposed the image, and my end result is an image with the correct compression type but unfortunately its solid black instead of black and white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibTiff.net is a little bulky because it's based off LibTiff, which has its own set of problems.

My company ([Atalasoft](http://www.atalasoft.com)) has the ability to do that fairly easily, and the [free version of the SDK](http://www.atalasoft.com/free-dotnet-image-sdk) will do the task you want with a few restrictions.  The code for re-encoding a file would look like this:

```
public bool ReencodeFile(string path)
{
    AtalaImage image = new AtalaImage(path);
    if (image.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Pixel1bppIndexed)
    {
        TiffEncoder encoder = new TiffEncoder();
        encoder.Compression = TiffCompression.Group4FaxEncoding;
        image.Save(path, encoder, null); // destroys the original - use carefully
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Things you should be aware of:

- this code will only work properly on 1bpp images
- this code will **NOT** work properly on multi-page TIFFs
- this code does **NOT** preserve metadata within the original file

and I would want the code to at least check for that.  If you are inclined to have a solution that better preserves what's in the content of the file, you would want to do this:

```
public bool ReencodeFile(string origPath, string outputPath)
{
    if (origPath == outputPath) throw new ArgumentException("outputPath needs to be different from input path.");
    TiffDocument doc = new TiffDocuemnt(origPath);

    bool needsReencoding = false;
    for (int i=0; i < doc.Pages; i++) {
        if (doc.Pages[i].PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Pixel1bppIndexed) {
            doc.Pages[i] = new TiffPage(new AtalaImage(origPath, i, null), TiffCompression.Group4FaxEncoding);
            needsReencoding = true;
        }
    }
    if (needsReendcoding)
        doc.Save(outputPath);
    return needsReencoding;
}
```

This solution will respect all pages within the document as well as document metadata.

Comment: thanks. I m still trying to use the above methodology to solve my case. If you can help with that. Please let me know.

Comment: Also, what if the image is not originally 1bpp ?

Comment: You cannot encode anything but 1bpp in CCITT.  For other bit depths, you have to select a different codec (flate or jpeg typically). I would advise that you spend a little time reading up on image compression and codecs.  Also, if you look at the TIFF spec and think "I can totally write this format myself" - think again, it's subtle and sloppy (an unusual combination).

Comment: for the very first statement :- Atalasoft.Imaging.AtalaImage image = new Atalasoft.Imaging.AtalaImage(fileName);

I get the error

Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.

Comment: Philo - I would call in to our support line - they're good people (and engineers like you)

Comment: haha, I called and the lady said "We don't provide phone support for the free sdk version" haha

Comment: OK - the problem might be the environment - are you running in full trust?  If so the assembly needs partial, IIRC.

Comment: elaborate? How do I give partial IIRC to my Visual Studio's 2010 environment.

Comment: https://www.atalasoft.com/KB/article.aspx?id=10340 (had it backwards - needs full trust, likely).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46465/discussion-between-plinth-and-philo)

Comment: Worked, I was using the anyCPU dlls, instead the x86 worked. However the compression method threw an exception because my image is LZW (original compression) and not 1bpp.