# Detect if code is running as a service

Tags: .net, windows-services

Is there a way for an .NET library to detect whether or not it is being run as a service?

My library can be run either way. But when its run as a service, developers need to call an additional method indicating that fact or certain features won't work correctly. I want my library, which handles logging, to write a warning if it is used in a service without that method being called.

Comment: Why not just have it call that method for the user, or does it take additional arguments?

Comment: We're having a similar issue.  For one thing, it needs to know whether its safe to invoke any UI stuff.  Still investigating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I Running as a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200163/am-i-running-as-a-service)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices) NuGet package and use the `WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService()` helper method.

For Linux you can use [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Systemd/) and the `SystemdHelpers.IsSystemdService()` method.

Answer (score 15):

After much searching through intellisense, the debugger, and documentation we weren't able to find anything strictly reliable.  It may be possible to get the current process Id and try to find out if that process is registered with the SCM, but while .NET provides a way to get a collection of all the services, their process Ids are not among the information available. Comparing the process name to service names is possible but not necessarily reliable.

However, there are two things that are relatively easy to check and may suffice for the distinction you need, if not exactly "Is this code running as a service?"

`System.Environment.UserInteractive` : (as Stephen Martin noted) If this is true, it can't be a service. Most processes which are not a service (nor a device driver) will say true. Some console apps may say false when run in non-interactive circumstances such as part of a build process.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId` : (which I think is the same thing Pierre was getting at) If this is not 0, it was not started as a service.  Most normal applications will not be in session 0 (with some not-so-normal exceptions as noted by Pierre and Stephen).  The biggest question is how this behaves under an older OS such as XP or before.  XP and Windows 2000 apparently have services running in session 0, but normal applications will be in session 0 as well.  Some configurations of XP (eg. not in a domain) allow multiple user sessions at the same time and they each get a different session id, but the first one gets session 0. So it's not as effective a check prior to Vista.

So, depending on what you actually need to distinguish, one or both of these checks might work for you.

Comment: The `UserInteractive` property will be `true` if the "Allow service to interact with desktop" check box in the Service Properties is checked.

Comment: Thanks for the caveat, @JonSeigel.  What OS was that introduced in?  If it existed pre-Vista then it undermines the check (unless user-interactive is what you actually care about).  On Vista and later, the check of `SessionId` is more reliable, anyway.  But, this caveat means that the OS version must be checked (if pre-Vista is supported) to determine the reliability of `SessionId` vs. needing to check `UserInteractive` for a semi-reliable hint.

Comment: BTW, in following some of the associated links, I just noticed an answer on a similar question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200163/am-i-running-as-a-service ) which demonstrates reflecting the entry assembly and its `EntryPoint` and checking whether the class is derived from `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`.  That may be a fairly useful approach for an independent library to determine whether it is running within a launched service.

Comment: The check box has been there for as long as I can remember... though I don't have an old OS handy to verify, I'm pretty sure it's in Windows XP, and possibly earlier than that. I like the command-line parameter answer in that question; it seems the only truly reliable way.

Comment: @JonSeigel, but the whole point is that you can't rely on the user or third-party developer to use such an API without mistake, so when creating a commercial-grade library to be included in other developers' apps a method of determining it from within the library using the framework/OS is the only way to make it bulletproof (at least as much as possible).  In other cases, where you *can* control the external app as well, an API to tell the common library which way it's invoked can be easier to rely on.  I really like the reflection answer I found, assuming it works reliably in all cases.

Comment: I agree. The problem is that there's currently *no 100% reliable way* that's available in the core frameworks to get this information. If that's not available, then anything built on top of it is inevitably also unreliable. The advantage of the command-line (or API) parameter is that at least the behaviour of the callee will be *predictable*, instead of using one of several "auto-detect" mechanisms which all have slightly different behaviour under different circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't really any way to tell if your library is running in the context of a service or not though you can use Environment.UserInteractive to make a guess.

But generally a library should never depend on its application context. A library should provide services to an application and if it requires different parameters depending on how it is called it should require the application to provide those parameters.

Your library probably does not act differently strictly based on whether or not it is hosted within a service but rather there is some information about the service environment or user that your library needs to be informed of. The application should inform the library of the necessary conditions or information, the library should not guess on its own.

### Edit

Use overloaded methods if necessary and/or simply fail if all the information necessary is not provided.

Comment: Knowing in what context your app is running is relevant if you need to do work on disk and you care what your default working directory is. Although I suppose you could just hard-code the path.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably check that you are running in session zero (at least if you are targeting Vista). You can use `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`, like in this sample:

```
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  private static extern int WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
```

Comment: That's a good API call you can use to make a guess but there can be non-service apps running in session 0 as well as services.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You are right. A non-interactive executable launched by the task scheduler would land there too.

Comment: That sounds like a good thing to me. Any of the stuff I don't wnat services to do I probably don't want non-interactive tasks doing either.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way is to apply a command line switch to the entry in the registry under *HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\MyService\ImagePath* and then check for that switch in your main function.

You then know if you were started by services.exe or not. Yeah it's a hack.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but how about getting the list of services using ServiceController.GetServices and check your process's ID against those?

("How to get running windows service process id ?": http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/a979351c-800f-41e7-b153-2d53ff6aac29 )

Comment: An interesting idea. Too bad I'm not a services developer any more, I would have liked to see how that plays out.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have a look at the user context of your application.  If you see that it is running as the "SYSTEM" user, then you are running as a service (or at least with service-level permissions).

Comment: Many, if not most, services do not run (or shouldn't run) as the SYSTEM user so this wouldn't really help. Also, non-service applications can be running as the SYSTEM user.

Comment: Yes, this wouldn't work.  You can, in the configuration of a Windows Service, specify an account that the service should run as.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by 0xA3 to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974828/how-do-we-tell-if-a-c-application-is-launched-as-a-windows-service) actually contains C# code to query the SCM, much like Rob Parker describes in his answer.