# ServiceController.ServiceName doesn't throw InvalidOperationException when the Windows service is not installed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

According to the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.servicename?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#exceptions

The `ServiceController.ServiceName` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if "The service was not found."

But running this code, it runs without throwing an exception:

```
var serviceController = new ServiceController();
serviceController.ServiceName = "Not.Existing.Service";
```

I, personally, don't believe this check on the service status happens upon setting the `ServiceName` (on the creation of the `ServiceControler` object). But the documentation is not clear when the exception is thrown exactly on this property.

There's also a possibility that the exception is thrown on getting the value from the `ServiceName`, I tried the following scenario:

1. Installed a service
2. Ran the code (below)
3. Paused the debugger on line 3
4. Uninstalled the service
5. Continued running the code

No exception occurred!

```
/*1*/ serviceController.ServiceName = "Existing.Service";
/*2*/ serviceController.Start();
/*3*/ var serviceName = serviceController.ServiceName;
```

I also found other questions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554116/how-to-check-if-a-windows-service-is-installed-in-c-sharp)) that none of the answers mention this property when checking whether a Windows service is installed or not.

Note: my problem is not trying to figure out how to check whether a Windows service is installed or not, but to understand when the exception is thrown on the `ServiceName` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-serviceprocess-servicecontroller-ctor(system-string)) with `string` argument to make (an attempt to make) a link with an existing service.

> Initializes a new instance of the ServiceController class that is associated with an existing service on the local computer.

The constructor will not throw an exception in case the service does not exist, but accessing that `ServiceName` property `get` will throw one as documented.

Below example throws that exception.

```
var serviceController = new ServiceController("Not.Existing.Service");
var serviceName = serviceController.ServiceName;  // << Exception thrown.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source code here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/src/System/ServiceProcess/ServiceController.cs) you will see when this exception is thrown.  There are several opportunities for ServiceController to throw this exception on the service name.  Specifically, look in the `private void GenerateNames()` definition.  This function is only called in the getters for `ServiceName` and `DisplayName` and that's when you'll probably encounter this exception.

Comment: Thanks, I actually relied on the NuGet page of the [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/) to get a reference to the source code, but I didn't find it there, so I went to [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceProcess/System/ServiceProcess/ServiceController.cs,3e05ca928fc6faf9) and it wasn't helpful at all!

Answer (score 0):

If you read [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/src/System/ServiceProcess/ServiceController.cs#L261) code, it is clearly mentioned that it does not throw exceptions for invalid service names (It does only validation [check](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1d15f2140f7eb30a976c66290491ec89cd628da0/src/libraries/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/src/System/ServiceProcess/ServiceBase.cs#L290)) on the setter of `ServiceController`'s `ServiceName`

Comment: Thanks, I actually relied on the NuGet page of the [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController/) to get a reference to the source code, but I didn't find it there, so I went to [referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceProcess/System/ServiceProcess/ServiceController.cs,3e05ca928fc6faf9) and it wasn't helpful at all!