# How to pass HostControl instance to custom host service in TopShelf?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, topshelf

This [question has been asked elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740658/how-to-detect-if-topshelf-is-running-in-console-mode), but there is no indication of how I get an instance of a `HostControl` as the post suggests.  My TopShelf main program looks like this:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        HostFactory.Run(CreateHost);
    }

    private static void CreateHost(HostConfigurator x)
    {
        x.UseLog4Net();

        x.Service<EventBroker>(s =>
        {
            s.ConstructUsing(name => new EventBroker());
            s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());
            s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());
        });

        x.StartAutomatically();

        x.RunAsNetworkService();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10):

Change WhenStarted to have HostControl passed to it like this

```
   s.WhenStarted((tc, hostControl) => tc.Start(hostControl));
```

Per TopShelf documentation here
http://topshelf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/config_api.html

Comment: hostControl:  CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'bool'