# Set 'Start Parameters' on Service Installation with .Net ServiceInstaller?

Tags: .net, service, installation

I am currently writing a little windows service application and I can successfully in/uninstall it etc via something like this:

```
        serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        serviceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "ABC";
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        serviceInstaller.Description = "DEF";
        Installers.AddRange(new Installer[] { serviceProcessInstaller, serviceInstaller });
```

... but I apparently cannot set the startup parameters there... or can I? I'd rather not go ahead and modify the registry later on.. therefore the Question... is there any way I can set these parameters programatically?

Comment: Are you referring to command line parameters? Why not use the app.config to configure your service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to add start parameters on service installation:

[Am I Running as a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200163/am-i-running-as-a-service/2111492#2111492)

Answer (score 9):

Here's a more concise answer:

In your ServiceInstaller class (the one that uses the Installer as a base class), add the following two overrides:

```
public partial class ServiceInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer {

    public ServiceInstaller () {
         ...
    }

    protected override void OnBeforeInstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState) {
        Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] += "\" /service";
        base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
    }

    protected override void OnBeforeUninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState) {
        Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] += "\" /service";
        base.OnBeforeUninstall(savedState);
    }


}
```

Comment: +1, but this doesn't handle quotes correctly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862580/using-installutil-to-install-a-windows-service-with-startup-parameters for the same solution, but with the quotes fixed. Also, it doesn't seem necessary to do this for uninstall - for me the service uninstalls fine without adjusting the path.

Comment: E.M, this solution is only looking incorrect. And your alternative solution is really incorrect while looking good. It happens because later .NET encloses whole value of assemblypath into quotes. And this particular solution is a hack to make command line correct.

Comment: @bugfixr, it would be more correct to change added string to "\" /service \"" in your sample. So all quotes will be balanced in the end, The only side effect will be additional empty command line argument to service.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me and I'm not sure how it got so many upvotes from others.  It did lead me to the solution though.  I had to update the following to include a leading double quote in the path.  So I changed `Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] += "\" /service";` to be `Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] = $"\"{Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]} \" --service";` instead.

Answer (score 7):

The parameters can be set by P/Invoking the ChangeServiceConfig API. They appear after the quoted path and file name to your executable in the lpBinaryPathName argument.

The parameters will be made available to your service when it starts through the Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

(Main is traditionally located in a file called Program.cs).

The following shows how you might modify an installer to call this API after the normal service installation logic runs. The parts of this that you most likely will need to modify are in the constructor.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;

namespace ServiceTest
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private string _Parameters;

        private ServiceProcessInstaller _ServiceProcessInstaller;
        private ServiceInstaller _ServiceInstaller;

        public ProjectInstaller()
        {
            _ServiceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            _ServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

            _ServiceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService;
            _ServiceProcessInstaller.Password = null;
            _ServiceProcessInstaller.Username = null;

            _ServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "Service1";

            this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
                _ServiceProcessInstaller,
                _ServiceInstaller});

            _Parameters = "/ThisIsATest";
        }

        public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);

            IntPtr hScm = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
            if (hScm == IntPtr.Zero)
                throw new Win32Exception();
            try
            {  
                IntPtr hSvc = OpenService(hScm, this._ServiceInstaller.ServiceName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
                if (hSvc == IntPtr.Zero)
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                try
                {
                    QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG oldConfig;
                    uint bytesAllocated = 8192; // Per documentation, 8K is max size.
                    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)bytesAllocated); 
                    try
                    {
                        uint bytesNeeded;
                        if (!QueryServiceConfig(hSvc, ptr, bytesAllocated, out bytesNeeded))
                        {
                            throw new Win32Exception();
                        }
                        oldConfig = (QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG));
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                    }

                    string newBinaryPathAndParameters = oldConfig.lpBinaryPathName + " " + _Parameters;

                    if (!ChangeServiceConfig(hSvc, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
                        newBinaryPathAndParameters, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null, null))
                        throw new Win32Exception();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (!CloseServiceHandle(hSvc))
                        throw new Win32Exception();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!CloseServiceHandle(hScm))
                    throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(
            string lpMachineName,
            string lpDatabaseName,
            uint dwDesiredAccess);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern IntPtr OpenService(
            IntPtr hSCManager,
            string lpServiceName,
            uint dwDesiredAccess);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
        private struct QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG {
            public uint dwServiceType;   
            public uint dwStartType;
            public uint dwErrorControl;
            public string lpBinaryPathName;
            public string lpLoadOrderGroup;
            public uint dwTagId;
            public string lpDependencies;
            public string lpServiceStartName;
            public string lpDisplayName;
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool QueryServiceConfig(
            IntPtr hService,
            IntPtr lpServiceConfig,
            uint cbBufSize,
            out uint pcbBytesNeeded);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool ChangeServiceConfig(
            IntPtr hService,
            uint dwServiceType,
            uint dwStartType,
            uint dwErrorControl,
            string lpBinaryPathName,
            string lpLoadOrderGroup,
            IntPtr lpdwTagId,
            string lpDependencies,
            string lpServiceStartName,
            string lpPassword,
            string lpDisplayName);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(
            IntPtr hSCObject);

        private const uint SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = 0xffffffffu;
        private const uint SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf003fu;
        private const uint SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = 0xf01ffu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome - not as elegantly as I hoped it would be, but thanks!

Comment: This may work, but it's unnecessarily complex. See **bugfixr**'s answer for much simpler code - no P/Invoke required.

Answer (score 3):

There is a managed way to add start parameters to a services (not in the "Start parameters"/"Startparameter" section of the management console (services.msc) but in "Path to executable"/"Pfad zur EXE-Datei" like all the windows' native services do).

Add the following code to your subclass of System.Configuration.Install.Installer: (in C#-friendly VB-Code)

```vb
'Just as sample
Private _CommandLineArgs As String() = New String() {"/Debug", "/LogSection:Hello World"}

''' <summary>Command line arguments without double-quotes.</summary>
Public Property CommandLineArgs() As String()
  Get
    Return _CommandLineArgs
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As String())
    _CommandLineArgs = value
  End Set
End Property

Public Overrides Sub Install(ByVal aStateSaver As System.Collections.IDictionary)
  Dim myPath As String = GetPathToExecutable()
  Context.Parameters.Item("assemblypath") = myPath
  MyBase.Install(aStateSaver)
End Sub

Private Function GetPathToExecutable() As String
  'Format as something like 'MyService.exe" "/Test" "/LogSection:Hello World'
  'Hint: The base class (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller) adds simple-mindedly
  '      a double-quote around this string that's why we have to omit it here.
  Const myDelimiter As String = """ """ 'double-quote space double-quote
  Dim myResult As New StringBuilder(Context.Parameters.Item("assemblypath"))
  myResult.Append(myDelimiter)
  myResult.Append(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Join(CommandLineArgs, myDelimiter))
  Return myResult.ToString()
End Function
```

Have fun!

chha

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do in managed code.

But there is one decent solution though. If all you want is having the same executable for windows service and GUI (most common scenario). You don't even need parameters. Just check in Main method for `System.Environment.UserInteractive` property and decide what to do...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        // start your app normally
    }
    else
    {
        // start your windows sevice
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not an anwer to the original question

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason my QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG struct wasn't getting the full value of lpBinaryPathName, only the first character. Changing it to the class below seemed to fix the problem. There is complete code at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/QueryServiceConfig.html

**Edit:** Also note this sets the "Path to executable" of the windows service but does not set the "Start parameters" of the windows service.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class QUERY_SERVICE_CONFIG
{
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwServiceType;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwStartType;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwErrorControl;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpBinaryPathName;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpLoadOrderGroup;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public UInt32 dwTagID;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpDependencies;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpServiceStartName;
    [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public String lpDisplayName;
}
```