# Pass data from ServiceInstaller class to ServiceBase derived class in C#

Tags: c#, windows, installation, service

I currently am passing a string from the command line into my server installer class which I then access using this.Context.Parameters["whatever"]. Is there any way I can then pass this string on into my actual service class to be used by it at runtime or do I need to save it to the drive in an ini or add it to the registry and then read it from my service at runtime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set 'Start Parameters' on Service Installation with .Net ServiceInstaller ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652654/set-start-parameters-on-service-installation-with-net-serviceinstaller)

Comment: Note: see second answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652654

Comment: Yeah thanks guys I got what I needed in that post. What a horrible way of having to do things with all that P/invoke code but well done to the author all the same.