# How do I determine if a class library is running in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#

I have a class library.  How do I determine if it is running in a Windows Service versus something else?  For example a console application, WPF, ASP.NET, WinForms?

Comment: It's usually better, if the calling "environment" matters, that you define an interface that your callers have to implement, that lets *them* choose how best to adapt to their "environment". That way, your code doesn't have to contain swiss army knives to deal with such factors. Of course, once you've defined such an interface, you're free to provide default implementations of the interface that are suitable for different "environments" - but leave it up to your callers to select the correct one (or choose their own implementation)

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: I just found this stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200163/am-i-running-as-a-service

Comment: @Greg''Wildman''Finzer Just as a matter of interest, why does you class library need to know if it's running in a service?

Comment: Matt, Dennis, sorry, I cannot answer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to determine if you are allowed to display any user interface, use:

[`Environment.UserInteractive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx)