# How to check if executable started as service or from SYSTEM account?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a program that can be installed and started as service, or can be started from SYSTEM account using the 'at' command. I need to find a way to know if the executable was started as service or from SYSTEM account, so I could know if I need to call ServiceBase.Run or perform other work at the executable entry point (Main function).

`Environment.UserInteractive` is false in both situations.

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsSystem` is true in both situations.

I'd like not to pass any command line arguments to solve this.

Entry point's `ReflectedType.BaseType.FullName` doesn't work either.

Comment: Open as a service and check it's status?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I Running as a Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200163/am-i-running-as-a-service)

Comment: @HuorSwords no, it is not, as in both situations I'm runnins as SYSTEM account...

Comment: The accepted answer on that question looks like it would work for you - it checks whether you're running from ServiceBase or not.

Comment: @Richard well, I tested it out even before asking this question and in an in any situation the BaseType.FullName is System.Object...

Comment: Using a command line argument is simple and easy to understand and maintain. You can add a `-service` argument when you install the service.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at the parent of your process.

```
public static bool IsRunningAsService() 
{
    return Process.GetCurrentProcess().Parent().ProcessName == "services";
}
```